# Python) to_csv: my csv file data is separated and pushed back

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm saving my pd.DataFrame with
"""df.to_csv('df.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig)"""

my csv file have a problem...
[please see rows, where have content2-1, content2-2, and content2-3 in this pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1tPT.png)

Before saving(to_csv), there was no problem. All the data had right columns, 'content2' was not separated. but after df -> csv...
'content2' is all separated, and the others of 'id2' are allocated to the wrong columns.
"2018-04-21" have to be in column D, 0 with E,F,G, and url must be in column I.

why this happen? because of large csv file?(774,740KB), because of language?(Korean), or csv cannot recognize enter key?(All data with problems such as content2 were separated based on the enter key.)

how can I resolve this? I have no idea

Comment: Check if there are new line '\n' characters added in those malformed rows

Comment: You might have cells (in columns on the righthand side of your dataframe) with multiline text or generally with characters clashing with Excel import rules for csv's. As @rayad wrote, try using `to_excel()` instead of `to_csv()`.

Comment: It was too late but, I found the reason for this. This was because of escape code... word '\r' and '\n' ruined my data... thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I never figured out the reason for this.. I assumed it was something to do with the size of the data i was working with and excel not liking it.

What worked for me though was using .to_excel() instead of to_csv(). I know, far from a perfect answer, but thought id put it here incase it is enough for your case